# 404 error , request resource is not available

Tags: java, servlets

.. but I guess I have done every thing right..please suggest

I need to know how to make a simple servlet application..Is there any thing to set in environment variables before proceeding..I have created helloworld servlet pgm but getting 404 error requested resource is not available..

**servlet class**

```
package com.ignis;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>devProj</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Hello</welcome-file>


    </welcome-file-list>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Close the PrintWriter object

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: unnecessary. Container does that already. Even more, a 404 means that the requested resource does not exist (or, that the request URL being used is wrong), so the servlet is never invoked in any way.

Answer (score 4):

The servlet class declaration should be

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ignis.Hello</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

You need the fully qualified class name of your `HttpServlet` implementation. I am surprised it even runs.

Answer (score 4):

You have to provide the fully qualified name of the servlet class in the `web.xml`. Like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ignis.Hello</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```